# How do I stop background call while going to another viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, swift3

I don't know how to stop this call without using the timer concept. Today, when trying to profile the project I came across this allocation memory get increasing every time because of following function:

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.5, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[index]
    }) { (finished) in
        var currentIndex = index + 1
        if currentIndex == self.colors.count { currentIndex = 0 }
        self.startAnimation(index: currentIndex)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one simple thing, mention one flag,

Initially it should,

```
var isViewDissappear = false
```

Then,

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        isViewDissappear = true
    }
```

Then check that flag while giving call again,

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.5, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.view.backgroundColor = self.colors[index]
        }) { (finished) in
            var currentIndex = index + 1
            if currentIndex == self.colors.count { currentIndex = 0 }
            if !self.isViewDissappear {
                self.startAnimation(index: currentIndex)
            }
        }
    }
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a retain cycle by capturing strong reference to `self` to the animation closure. Which means that your `self` is owned by the closure, and closure owned by `self` - this causes a leak mentioned by you (increase of memory usage). You can break the cycle by capturing **weak** reference to `self` by using capture list (read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID103)). Try this:

```
func startAnimation(index: Int) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0, delay: 0.5, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut], animations: { [weak self]
        self?.view.backgroundColor = self?.colors[index]
    }) { (finished) in
        var currentIndex = index + 1
        if currentIndex == self?.colors.count { currentIndex = 0 }
        self?.startAnimation(index: currentIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i was scared only for to stop call, i'm using ARC.